# PHP preg_replace image extensions that aren't proceeded by a question mark?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to use preg_replace to append a query string on image paths for cache busting purposes.

Currently I am using the following, however it does not account for an edge case where image extensions already have a query string.

```
$html = preg_replace('/\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/i', '.${1}?v=1', $html);
```

How can I exclude matches that are followed by a question mark?

Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this page may help you with this problem.

https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

For your scenario, try this regex: `/\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)(?!\?)/i`.